# Filling empty column with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wanna fill my dataset with condition, by using columns in dataset.
[You see it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxJIE.png)

And by column "Average hour", I create column "Car type" and fill it by this function:

```
def sample(df, i, steps):
    for i in range(steps):
        if(df["Average hour"].all())<70:
            df["Car type"].fillna("Mini truck").all()
        elif(df["Average hour"].all()>70 and df["Average hour"].all()<90):
            df["Car type"].fillna("VAN").all()
        elif(df["Average hour"].all()>90 and df["Average hour"].all()<100):
            df["Car type"].fillna("Bus").all()
        elif(df["Average hour"].all()>100 and df["Average hour"].all()<120):
            df["Car type"].fillna("SUV").all()
        elif(df["Average hour"].all()>120):
            df["Car type"].fillna("PickUP truck").all()
    return df
```

When I created new column, it has full NaN values, according to this point, I used .fillna(), but terminal tells me use .all() too, but I still confused, this function isn't working.
If you will advice me, write with np.where, can you explain, how I use it?
May be I miss something?

Comment: Please avoid posting images of code and data. This is hard to copy'n'past. And if you have an error message, please post it, too. One additional hint. You are missing the reassignment! Try `df = df[].fillna()` in each `if` and `elif` line.

Comment: Note that if the input is exactly 70, 90, 100, or 120, it won't do anything because you are only checking if values are larger or less, but not equal to those values.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to create a categorical column. It's by using [**`pandas.cut`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html).

```
bins = [0, 70, 90, 100, 120, float("inf")]
labels = ['Mini truck', 'VAN', 'bus', 'SUV', 'PickUP truck']

df['Car Type'] = pd.cut(df['Average hour'], bins, labels=labels)
```

##### `>>> print(df)`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on your image I think [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html?highlight=apply#pandas.DataFrame.apply) with a custom function `f` solves it for you.

```
def f(x):
    if x<70:
        return "Mini truck"
    elif 70<x<90: # because of the logic befor this cloud simplified to x<90
        return "VAN"
    elif 90<x<100:
        return "Bus"
    elif 100<x<120:
        return "SUV"
    elif 120<x:
        return "PickUP truck"

df["Car type"] = df["Average Hour"].apply(f)
```

### Minimal Example

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

t="""Brand  Average Hour
Audi  122
BWM  89
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(t), sep="\s\s", index_col=0)
df["Car type"] = df["Average Hour"].apply(f)

>>> df 
       Average Hour      Car type
Brand                            
Audi            122  PickUP truck
BWM              89           VAN
```